# 'Generator' for Prime numbers in a range

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator, yield

Someone please help me out with this hackerrank problem that I am stuck for weeks now!
I am defining a function which has 2 arguments. The parameter 'num' is an integer and is the range up to which the prime number must be generated, and the parameter 'val' contains either 0 or 1. But it has another condition:
The prime numbers for 'num' value of 21 are - 2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19

1. If the value of 'val' is 0, then yield the values: 3 7 13 19 [odd index values]
2. If 'val' is 1, yield values should be: 2 5 11 17 [even index values]

I tried below code

```
def primenum(num, val):
    for i in range(3-val,num):
        if(i > 2):          
            for j in range(2,i):
                if(i%j == 0):
                    break
                else:
                    yield i
```

Comment: Have you tried first generating all the prime numbers up to `num` and going from there?

Comment: Keep track of how many primes you have found then modulo that amount against 2.

Comment: You do not need to examine the entire range `(2, i)`. For any i, there is a number j such that for any pair of factors x, y of i, at least one of x, y is less than or equal to j. You can think of this as the "multiplicative midpoint of i". I will leave it as a fun exercise for you to find that midpoint :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this helps:

```
def primenum(num, val):
    primes = []
    for i in range(2, num):
        for j in range(2, int(i / 2) + 1):
            if i % j == 0:
                break
        else:
            primes.append(i)
        
    for i in range(1 - val, len(primes), 2):
        yield primes[i]

prime1 = list(primenum(21, 0)) # [3, 7, 13, 19]
prime2 = list(primenum(21, 1)) # [2, 5, 11, 17]
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is going to be used in a production setting, you should use a more efficient algorithm for generating primes, but with what you have so far:

```py
def primenum(num,val):
    prime_count = 0
    for test_number in range(2,n):
        has_prime_factor = False
        for comparison in range(2,test_number):
            if test_number % comparison == 0:
                has_prime_factor = True
                break
        if not has_prime_factor:
            prime_count += 1
            if prime_count % 2 == val:
                yield test_number
```

Answer (score -2):

def primegenerator(num, val):
# Write your code here

```
for i in range(2,num):
    for j in range(2,i//2+1):
        if i%j == 0:
            break
    else:
        if val == 1:
            yield i
            val -= 1
        else:
            val +=1
```